# fullpage.js multiple onLeave and afterLoad events

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm trying to implement afterLoad and onLeave multiple events in my `fullpage.js` for different sections. But only the last one seems to be working, what can be wrong here?

If I remove the last one though, the first one works well. So it looks like I combine them in a wrong way, so one disables the other.

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
      onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
          if (nextIndex == 3 || nextIndex == 1) {
              $('.aboutme').hide("slide", {
                  direction: "left"
              }, 200);
          }


      },
      afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
          if (index == 2) {
              $('.aboutme').show("slide", {
                  direction: "left"
              }, 200);
          }

      },

      onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {

          if (nextIndex == 2) {
              $('.titlea').hide("slide", {
                  direction: "right"
              }, 200, function() {
                  $('.titleb').hide("slide", {
                      direction: "right"
                  }, 200);
              });
          }

      },
      afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {

          if (index == 1) {
              $('.titlea').show("slide", {
                  direction: "right"
              }, 200, function() {
                  $('.titleb').show("slide", {
                      direction: "right"
                  }, 200);
              });
          }
      }
  });
```

To be more specific, what is the right way to combine multiple `onLeave` and `afterLoad` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seeing as you already have if clauses in your event functions, try this

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){                
            if (nextIndex == 3 || nextIndex == 1 ) {
                $('.aboutme').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 200);
            } else if (nextIndex == 2 ) {
                $('.titlea').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 700, function(){$('.titleb').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 200);});
            }
        },
        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
            if (index == 2){
                $('.aboutme').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 200);
            } else if (index == 1 ) {
                $('.titlea').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 700, function(){$('.titleb').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 200);});
            }
        }   

    });   

});
```

or use switch/case

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){  
            switch(nextIndex){
                case 3:
                case 1:
                    $('.aboutme').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 200);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $('.titlea').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 700, function(){$('.titleb').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 200);});
                    break;
            }
        },
        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
            switch(index){
                case 2:
                    $('.aboutme').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 200);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $('.titlea').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 700, function(){$('.titleb').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 200);});
                    break;
            }
        }   

    });   

});
```

so basically, you have one event callback function, and based on the parameters passed, you make your decision on actions to take.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you, that works. Will accept in few minutes.